# Laravel, find ids using query where those ids are in another table

Tags: php, laravel

I have two tables, `school_users` and `users`. I need to create a query, *using Eloquent*, that gets all users  where `user_id` equal `school_id`.
so the result must be more than one user, so that also I need to group the result by school_id

thank you in davance

Relations:
 User Model:

```
public function school()
{
    return $this->hasMany(SchoolUser::class);
}
```

SchoolUser Model:

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->hasMany(User::class);
}
```

`School_users` table:

```
+----+---------+------------+-------------+
| id | user_id |  school_id | created_at  |
+----+---------+------------+-------------+
|  1 |   79    |    79      | <SOME TIME> |
|  2 |   85    |    79      | <SOME TIME> |
|  3 |   86    |    85      | <SOME TIME> |
|  4 |   87    |    85      | <SOME TIME> |
+----+---------+------------+-------------+
```

`users` table:

```
+----+
| id | 
+----+-
|  79 | 
|  85 |
|  86 |
|  87 |    
+----+-
```

User Model:

```
public function getUsers()
{
    return $this
        ->leftJoin('school_users', $this->table . '.id', '=', 'school_users.school_id')
        ->select(
            $this->table . '.*',
            'school_users.school_id as school_id'
        )
        ->whereIn('users.id', '=', 'school_users.school_id')
        ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
        ->get();
}
```

Comment: Did you define any relations on your models?

Comment: Just so we're clear, the only row that should be returned is the one with an `id` of **1**?

Comment: @Jerodev yes I did

Comment: @Rwd what I want is to return the id of Users where this id is equal to school_id in school_users table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `whereColumn` to filter `user_id` equal to `school_id`,

and use `join` instead of `leftjoin`:

```php
public function getUsers()
{
    return $this
    ->join('school_users', function($join) {
        $join->on('school_users.user_id', '=', $this->table.'.id')
             ->whereColumn('school_users.user_id', 'school_users.school_id');
    })
    ->select
        (

            $this->table.'.*',
            'school_users.school_id as school_id'
        ) 
    ->orderBy($this->table.'.id','desc')
    ->get();   
    }
```